# HotChocolate GraphQL add type extension or schema at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I want to add a new type or query extension dynamically when a back end service registers at our API anytime at runtime. So on startup in ConfigureServices we basically just have a query with one test method:

```
services.AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddQueryType(t => t.Name("Query"))
        .AddType<Query>();
```

After startup I need to call AddType or AddTypeExtensionsFromString to add the new methods/types to the API. Is there an way to do this with HotChocolate?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using type modules.

Create a custom type module that implements `ITypeModule`.
This interface has a methoc CreateTypesAsync. This method is called during the schema building process and you can return low level types.

The interface also defines a Event `TypesChanged`. You can trigger this event whenever HotChocoalte should reload this TypeModule. Type modules can be registered in the DI and you can inject the module into the place where the schema reload should be triggered.

Some more documentation: https://chillicream.com/blog/2021/09/27/hot-chocolate-12#dynamic-schemas

Full example: https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate-examples/tree/master/misc/TypeModules